# How can i watch a filetype or a specific file on visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How can I do something (or run some code/tool) when specific file type or specific file changes/saved in visual studio

Comment: Keep the file open, and turn off 'automatically reload changes'. A dialog box will pop asking you if you want to reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio Macros:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Or

Create VS Add-in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/80493a3w.aspx

Or

Create desktop app which monitors file system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: thanks but i think visual studio macros are obselete and microsoft will not support it in next versions.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d8410838-085b-4647-8c42-e31b669c9f11/

Comment: If you don't want use macros - there is more complicated way - you can create a plugin for VS. Also you can create a separate desktop app which monitors file system and o some actions when files of specific types are modified.

Comment: Edited my answer to contain all options